# Regarding an example in "function invocation and the execution stack"

Tags: javascript, html

Rregarding an example in "function invocation and the execution stack" .

```js
function a() {
  b();
  var c;
}

function b() {
  var d;
}

a();
var d;
```

why isn't "var d" stored in the memory of the global execution context? I thought functions and variables that are not inside other functions were supposed to be attached to the global object in the global execution stack.

Comment: What makes you think it isn't? There are two different `d` variables, once is global, the other is local to `b`.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? It declares variables but never uses them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be in the global execution context and inside of b()'s execution context when it gets invoked. JavaScript allows shadowing of variables So when inside of b()'s context the variable d defined there is what you get, but elsewhere you would get global's variable d

```js
function a() {
  b();
  var c;
}
 
function b() {
  var d;
  console.log("var d inside b() ${d}");
}
 
a();
var d;
console.log("var d in global ${d}");
```